# Passing data to overridden base method in C#

Tags: c#

Bit of a dumb question, but I'm wondering what the accepted way of passing data from back to an overridden base method is in c#.

e.g. I guess I could do:

```
class A
{
    int x;
    public virtual void DoStuff() {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void DoStuff() {
        x = 1;
        base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

But is there a better method that for example doesn't require the use of a member variable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't understand the question, but have you considered adding a method in the base class that takes a parameter instead?

Comment: Thanks the answers - all interesting :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution can involve the use of a protected method that has an argument to reuse code from the base class.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void DoStuff() {
        DoStuffInternal(0);
    }
    protected void DoStuffInternal(int x) {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void DoStuff() {
        DoStuffInternal(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a parameter?

```
class A
{
    public virtual void DoStuff(int x) {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void DoStuff(int x) {
        //do stuff
        int y = 1
        base.DoStuff(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to expose the (int x) to consumers of B

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
abstract class A
{
    protected abstract int X { get; }
    public void DoStuff() {
        Console.WriteLine(X);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected override int X { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method) design pattern:

```
class A
{

    public void DoStuff() {
        var x = DoGetX();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    protected abstract int DoGetX();
}

class B : A
{
    protected override int DoGetX() {
      return 1;
    }
}
```

For almost every developer property is looks like simple wrapper around field, and we know that there are no such thing like virtual fields. So I think that abstract method is much more preferable solution in this case(we already discussed differences between properties and methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101646/is-object-creation-in-getters-bad-practice/2103719#2103719)).