# Dynamically create static fields C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to dynamically create static fields in a class?

```
class Pages
{
    private static T getPages<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var page = new T();
        PageFactory.InitElements(Browsers.getDriver, page);
        return page;
    }
    public static HomePage Home => getPages<HomePage>();
    public static DashboardPage Dashboard => getPages<DashboardPage>();
    public static ProfilePage Profile => getPages<ProfilePage>();
}
```

Right now I'm adding them one by one myself. Is there a way to dynamically add them? `HomePage`, `DashboardPage` and `ProfilePage` live under MyProject.Pages namespace, if I know how to dynamically create the static fields, I could loop through that namespace and dynamically create them.

Comment: how often you do this? and how many pages we are talking about?

Comment: I have over 70 pages.

The pages class is to make my life easier in the tests so I can refer to a page  `Pages.HomePage.Login()`. Right now each time I create a new page I'm adding it manually to the `Pages` class.

Comment: Is that much easier than `Pages.GetPage<HomePage>().Login()`? That wouldn't require anything dynamic, as far as I can see. (I'd definitely call it `GetPage` rather than `GetPages`, as it's only creating a single page...)

Comment: Are you asking about code generation? Or are you expecting something that happens at runtime? I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: @JohnWu I was looking for something that happens at runtime. I like Jon Skeet's idea and will use this. However I'm curious to see if it's possible in C# to dynamically create  static fields at runtime and to see how it's done.

Comment: It is not possible to create static fields at runtime (`dynamic` aside). After all, you're writing tests which access those fields at compile-time - if those fields were only available at runtime, this would not work.

Comment: Jon's answer is the way to go. Not only because it solves your issue, but because you really [ought to be using a method, not a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101646/is-object-creation-in-getters-bad-practice).

Answer (score 4):

What you ask isn't possible, as compiled code depends on the source it was compiled from. So unless you generate your sources dynamically (you could research `T4` or `T5` for that), a compiled class can not be extended in the way you describe.

However with a slightly different setup, the need for all this might become small or even absent. By making class `Pages` static, and then using it as follows: `using static <namespace>.Pages`, you can use its methods without prefixing them with the class name.

Full example (and accompanying [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M88QrK)):

```
using System;
using Project;
using static Project.Pages;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var home = GetPage<Home>();
        var dashboard = GetPage<Dashboard>();
        var profile = GetPage<Profile>();

        Console.WriteLine(home.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(dashboard.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(profile.GetType().Name);
    }
}

namespace Project
{
    public static class Pages
    {
        public static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
        {
            var page = new T();
            // ...
            return page;
        }
    }

    public class Home { /* ... */ }

    public class Dashboard { /* ... */ }

    public class Profile { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can then make it more compile-safe by making all Page classes implement an `IPage` interface, and adding a `where T: IPage` constraint to `GetPage<T>()`.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than adding properties, i would probably be easier if all those pages inherit from a common base class, and make a dictionary with a string as key. this way, you could easily add pages dynamically, without having to rely on generics.

```
public static pages = new Dictionary<string, IPage>{
   {"homepage", GetPages<HomePage>()},
   ...
}
```

or something like that, you probably don't even need a dictionary, you could do it with a list.

Even better would be to use an IOC container, and add a servicecollection extension to register all types that inherit from IPage. that way, you could just inject those pages wherever you need them, and it will register them automatically.

Comment: 1) This caches a single HomePage, whereas the OP's question creates a new HomePage per access (which is presumably important). 2) Relying on strings is less safe (and IMO significantly less desirable) then doing either `Pages.Home` or `Pages.GetPage<HomePage>()`

Comment: You're probably right about the strings, that's why i also said it may be interesting to just use a list. however, The ioc approach is very common, and could work out great if you register a module, that in turn registers it's pages in the container. that way, you don't even need to call getPage, you could just inject it.